# C++ Generate standard constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I often find myself writing very simple classes instead of C-style structs. They typically look like this:

```
class A
{
public:
  type mA;
  type mB;
  ...
  A(type mA,type mB,...) : mA(mA),mB(mB),... {}
}
```

Is that a sensible way of doing things? If yes, I was wondering whether there was any third party plugin out there or any handy short cut to automatically construct the text for the constructor (e.g. take the highlighted or existent member definitions, replace semicolons with commas, move everything on the same line, ...)? Thanks

Comment: Just as a style note I don't recommend putting it all on one line. Once you get over 2-3 attributes it's going to get unwieldy. Instead, put each initializer and probably each parameter on its own line. This makes it easier to add new items, they show up clearly in any source control diff, and it probably makes the code easier to read (remember that code is usually write-once, read-many).

Comment: Sidenote: Technically the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` in c++ is the default access specifier. If everything is going to be public, just make it a `struct` (i.e. replace `class` with `struct` in the above code and remove the `public:` access specifier)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just use plain aggregates:

```
struct A
{
  type mA;
  type mB;
  ...
};
```

Usage:

```
A x = { mA, mB, ... };
```

An aggregate has no custom constructors, destructor and assignment operator, and it allows for plenty of optimisations. Aggregate initialization with the brace syntax for example usually constructs the members in place without even a copy. Also you get the best possible copy and move constructors and assignment operators defined for you by the compiler.

Comment: The OP said "very simple classes". The need for a destructor would be the hallmark of a decidedly non-simple class! :-)

Comment: @Jeff: The OP does mention that he is doibg this for C-style structs. So you can prosume this.

Comment: Agreed. I did upvote this answer when I commented. I was just pointing out a shortcoming of using this answer as a general solution.

Comment: @kerrek It also has the potential to silently break things if you change the location of member variables.

Comment: @Chet: The same would apply to any "automatically" defined constructor, non?

Comment: @kerrek If I insert a new member variable of type 'type' between mA and mB the aggregate initializer will assign the 3rd value in the list to mB - not the second value as originally intended. If that value can be assigned to mB either by value, constructor or type conversion you won't be alerted to the change. Automatically generated copy and move constructors are built based on all members in the class so any change will be taken into account during compile time.

Comment: This doesn't work, period.  If you're defining a variable, it will pass the compiler, but break as soon as you modify the struct.  And if you're not defining a variable, but rather passing it as an argument, or using it as a member, the aggregate initialization syntax isn't allowed.  My code if full of `struct` which have a constructor, just so that I can use them rationally, without constantly having to declare unnecessary variables.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** previous version was c99, not c++. now it is c++

i think you can use {} initialization instead of writing constructor. or is it in c++0x? c99? i am not sure. but it looks like:

```
struct A myA = { 3,  5};
```

Comment: @Ali: huh, you could just delete it then? Or improve it?

Comment: don't  think; actually test it. PS it does not compile as c++

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it was a sensible way of doing it although OO fanatics might comment on the lack of encapsulation you have.
I know Visual Studio has code snippets built in which do half the job you are looking for but it depends on your IDE